# Xcode 6 Beta 5 Swift Playground: Cannot find symbol for CGRectMake()

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, swift-playground, cgrectmake

Since updating to Xcode 6 beta 5 my playground code will no longer compile/run and logs:

```
Playground execution failed: error: Couldn't lookup symbols: _CGRectMake
```

It should be simple enough and worked fine on the previous versions. The only code I am running up to that point is as follows:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import XCPlayground
import QuartzCore
let frameRect: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500)
var customView = UIView(frame: frameRect)
```

Just wondering if anyone else is having problems with Playground and found solutions. My hunch is that is just a beta bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try just removing the "make":

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import XCPlayground
import QuartzCore
let frameRect: CGRect = CGRect(0, 0, 500, 500)
var customView = UIView(frame: frameRect)
```

Also, you may get another weird error with your view when you import XCPlayground, so try this:

```
customView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500)` instead.

`CGRectMake` still works for me though... Did you create a new playground with beta 5? I've found it's best to always create a new playground for each new beta.

Comment: No joy. That was my first thought but when I copied my code over to a new Beta 5 project the error remained. Also your code still logs the same error for me. I may try reinstalling the whole thing again since it is still working for you. Thanks!

Comment: Ick, beta 5 caused a lot of weirdness for me. I ended up having to blow away all of my derived data directories to resolve some framework issues.

Comment: Here's a fun development: if I don't import XCPlayground and remove the related code the whole thing runs smoothly, I just can't see the result... Which is kind of the idea of the playground. So that's fun. I'm going to go ahead and reinstall.